# Error linking to Boost filesystem using cmake on cygwin

Tags: c++, boost, cygwin, cmake

I'm using cmake 2.8.9, g++ 3.4.4, and Boost 1.50. in Cygwin on Windows 8 64 bit.
Here is the error message I get.

> Linking CXX executable RayTracer.exe
>   CMakeFiles/RayTracer.dir/Ray_Tracer.cpp.o:Ray_Tracer.cpp:(.text+0x89c):
>   undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
>   CMakeFiles/RayTracer.dir/Ray_Tracer.cpp.o:Ray_Tracer.cpp:(.text+0x8a6):
>   undefined reference to`boost::system::generic_category()'
>   CMakeFiles/RayTracer.dir/Ray_Tracer.cpp.o:Ray_Tracer.cpp:(.text+0x8b0):
>   undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:
>   CMakeFiles/RayTracer.dir/Ray_Tracer.cpp.o: bad reloc address 0xb in
>   section`
>   .text$_ZN5boost6system14error_categoryD1Ev[boost::system::error_category::~error_category()]'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   CMakeFiles/RayTracer.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target
>   `RayTracer.exe' failed make[2]: *** [RayTracer.exe] Error 1
>   CMakeFiles/Makefile2:64: recipe for target`
>   CMakeFiles/RayTracer.dir/all' failed make[1]: ***
>   [CMakeFiles/RayTracer.dir/all] Error 2 Makefile:75: recipe for target
>   `all' failed make: *** [all] Error 2

From what I've seen, the usual problem is failing to link the boost system library, but I made sure to do that.  Here is the relevant portion of my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
#Edit: cmake can't find the static libraries on cygwin, so I'm setting this to false for now.
SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS FALSE)

FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.50 REQUIRED date_time program_options thread filesystem system unit_test_framework)
IF(${Boost_FOUND})
  INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
ENDIF()
add_executable(RayTracer
    Ray_Tracer.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(RayTracer ${Boost_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARIES})
```

And here's the line in my .cpp file that triggers the error:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the linker to link Boost.Filesystem and Boost.System libraries.

You can do:

```
target_link_libraries(RayTracer
                      ${Boost_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARIES}
                      ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARIES}
                      ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES}
                      )
```

or if you just want to link all the libs specified in your `find_package(Boost...)` call, you can do:

```
target_link_libraries(RayTracer ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

For further details on the `FindBoost` CMake module, see [the docs](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#module%3aFindBoost) or run:

```
cmake --help-module FindBoost
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it!  I figured it was something simple like that, I'm pretty new to cmake and boost.

Comment: CMake and Boost are both awesome... have fun!